# Data from JS variables is being cached

Tags: javascript, php, json, caching

I have a JSON file on my server that gets updated every 5 minutes. However, when refreshing my site after an update to the JSON file, the data is cached and is not showing the latest data until I hard refresh.

How can I avoid this and ensure that the latest data set is being shown?

I have this in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
```

Here my function that gets run on page load:

```
let buildings = [];

async function getWG() {
    let updated = await fetch('cron_log.txt');
    updated = await updated.text();
    let updateText = document.getElementById("updated");
    updateText.innerHTML = '';
    updateText.innerHTML = 'Updated: ' + updated + ' EST';
    console.log(updated);
    if(buildings.length < 1){
        let response = await fetch('wg_data.json');
        buildings = await response.json();  
        buildings.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.fee - b.fee;
        });
    }
    
    //console.log(buildings);
    
    let element = document.getElementById("mainData");
    element.innerHTML = '';
    
    //loop thru array of buildings
    for (var x = 0; x < buildings.length; x++){
        //document.write(buildings[x].community);
        if(!buildings[x].closed){
            let row = '<div class="row"><div class="col community">' + buildings[x].community + '</div><div class="col landid">' + buildings[x].landId + '</div><div class="col type">' + buildings[x].type + '</div><div class="col fee">' + (buildings[x].fee + 1000) + '</div><div class="col rank">' + buildings[x].rank + '</div></div>';
            element.innerHTML += row;     
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my PHP file that gets called every 5 min and retrieves the latest data, then saves to the JSON file:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = test.com;

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response,true);
```

Comment: How are you defining the `Expires` in the Response? Probably it can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires

Comment: Which file is cached where exactly?

Comment: Add a cachebuster to the URL.

Comment: One trick is to add a timestamp as a query string to the link that fetches the file. How you'd do this in your code is anybody's guess, since you haven't posted any

Comment: code has been added

Comment: @mickdeez Which of the files is being cached, *cron_log.txt* or *wg_data.json*? What http cache headers does your server send for them? Notice that the caching of the html page or the script file don't matter at all.

Comment: @Bergi - both seem to get cached. I've added my PHP code that calls an API to retrieve the data. I'm don't believe I'm setting any http cache headers?

Comment: @mickdeez Doesn't matter how you are updating the file in the server's file system. How are you serving it to the client?

Comment: @Bergi - I'm fetching it using my getWG() function, then looping through it and displaying it using innerHTML

Comment: @mickdeez That's the fetching that makes the request. Where is the code that makes your server respond? Is it php? Is it apache? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this:

```
        let response = await fetch('wg_data.json');
        buildings = await response.json();
```

it looks like you fetch a static file. You could configure your webserver to add a header to expire the data of this file immediately, which will tell the browser to not rely on its internal cache.

Alternatively, you can fool the browser to request a new file each time, thus avoiding using a local cache. Do that by creating a unique URL, such as:

```
        let response = await fetch('wg_data.json?t=' + new Date().valueOf());
        buildings = await response.json();
```

which produces a new URL each time, such as `'wg_data.json?t=1672100283407'`. The server ignores the URL parameter, and just delivers the file.

You might need to do the same for `fetch('cron_log.txt')` as well.

Comment: Correction: "*You **should** configure your webserver*"